# Regex getting url string

Tags: regex, preg-match

I trying to get the youtube url between [link= and ]
using this code. Why isn't it working?

**code**

```
(?<=[link=\s).*(?=\s])
```

**text**

```
a very long text before this
    [link=http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Fh3knetKm5U]and some text here
```

i need to get `http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Fh3knetKm5U`

Comment: What isn't working? Where's the code?

Comment: (?<=[link=\s).*(?=\s])

Comment: Why not `\[link=([^]]*)]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about simply:

```
\[link=(.*?)\]
```

Is there a reason you use lookbehinds?

More importantly, this looks like you are planning to implement text formatting. Have you considered using libraries like [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) or [ReST](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html)?

Example using the above regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile(r'\[link=(.*?)\]')
>>> txt = '''a very long text before this
...      [link=http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Fh3knetKm5U]and some'''
>>> p.findall(txt)
['http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Fh3knetKm5U']
```

Comment: nope. im just tring to get the url from a long text. i have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You are using unnecessarily the lookahead and lookbehind. These can simply do for you

```
\[link=(\S+)\]

\[link=([^\]]*)\]

\[link=(.+)\]

\[link=(.*?)\]
```